# Host Django Rest API on AWS ec2 using Apache

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, apache2

I have built a very basic API using the Django Rest Framework following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-rest-api-with-django-a-test-driven-approach-part-1

I have confirmed that this works on my local machine by following the instructions of the tutorial. Now I need to host this API on the internet. The easiest way to do this seems to be with AWS using Apache2 on an ec2, which I have attempted to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. I understand that I need to configure Apache2 for my application, which I have done following this tutorial: http://www.nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/koAayBejnjdNwYfc6 modifying values as needed. My Apache2 configuration file is located
here: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/djangorest.conf 
and contains the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/djangorest/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest
<Directory /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/djangorest>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/static/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ubuntu/API/djangorest/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My project is housed in the home directory of the ec2 instance like so: ~/API/djangorest/...

From here, shouldn't it be a simple matter of configuring Apache? I've waded through documentation for hours to no avail. When I type the public dns into a browser, I get the following message: "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

This is basically the first project I've ever done that isn't a console application, so It's likely that I'm missing something obvious. In short, I just need to know how to host this API so that I can make calls to it and modify my database. If there's an easier approach than what I'm taking, or if there's a better tutorial to follow, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You haven't said what's going wrong. Yes, configuring Apache as you have done, or an equivalent web server, is what you need to do.

Comment: What's wrong is that I simply can't call this API with a web browser or curl. I should theoretically be able to type the public dns into a web browser and have the API handle the request, right?

Comment: So what happens? Do you get an error page from Apache? What does it say? Is there anything in the Apache logs? Also, where exactly is that config you've posted? Show the whole file.